# Should CanExecute work forever or just when property is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command, relaycommand

I am working on a calculator. My view contains 16 `Button`s and 1 `TextBox`:

[image: Calculator with a TextBox on top and below a number block 0-9 an "AC" and an "=" button and buttons for mulitply, divide, subract and add on the right.]

`TextBox`'s `Text` property is bound to the `UserInput` property in `ViewModel`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="InputTextBox"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Background="#ECDBBA"
         Foreground="#191919"
         FontSize="30"
         Text="{Binding UserInput, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AddTextCommand AddTextCmnd { get; set; }
    public ClearTextCommand ClearTextCmnd { get; set; }
    public ShowResultCommand ShowResultCmnd { get; set; }

    private string _userInput = "0";
    public string UserInput
    {
        get { return _userInput; }
        set
        {
            if (UserInput != value)
            {
                _userInput = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserInput");                                    
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        AddTextCmnd = new AddTextCommand(this);
        ClearTextCmnd = new ClearTextCommand(this);
        ShowResultCmnd = new ShowResultCommand(this);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));            
    }
}
```

I have 3 commands: One to add text to `TextBox`, another to show the result, and a last one to clear the `TextBox`. **AC** and **"="** buttons (see screenshot) are bound to `ClearTextCommand` and `ShowResultCommand`.

```
public class ShowResultCommand : ICommand 
    {
        private ViewModel _viewModel;

        public ShowResultCommand(ViewModel viewModel)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
        }


        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_viewModel.UserInput != "0")
                return true;

            else
                return false;            
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            DataTable calculator = new DataTable();
            _viewModel.UserInput = calculator.Compute(_viewModel.UserInput, null).ToString();
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ClearTextCommand : ICommand
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel;

    public ClearTextCommand(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_viewModel.UserInput != "0")
            return true;

        else
            return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.UserInput = "0";
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

The program works well, but 2 commands share a problem. I don't know if it is my ignorance or not, but I didn't find anything in Google. I thought that my `CanExecute` methods work only when `UserInput` changed (property changed), but I put a breakpoint on the `CanExecute` methods of my commands and saw that they work forever in debug, like once `UserInput` is changed, `ShowResultCommand` and `ClearTextCommand`'s `CanExecute` methods work forever, they are called again and again in a loop. I am wondering if they should work this way? Shouldn't they be called just when `UserInput` is changed? This doesn't cause any error in my program, but I think there is something wrong with my commands.

So basically question is:

**Should `CanExecute` work in a loop while my app is running or should it work when a property related to the method is changed? If it should work in a loop, then everything is fine, but if not what is wrong with my commands?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***I thought that my `CanExecute` methods work only when UserInput changed(property changed).***

Yes and no. Your commands delegate the `CanExecuteChanged` event to the [`RequerySuggested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event of [`CommandManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandmanager?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). This is a common approach. The `CommandManager` is a WPF framework type responsible for:

> Provides command related utility methods that register `CommandBinding` and `InputBinding` objects for class owners and commands, add and remove command event handlers, and provides services for querying the status of a command.

The `RequerySuggested` event is only raised under a few not well documented circumstances:

> The `CommandManager` only pays attention to *certain conditions* in determining when the command target has changed, such as **change in keyboard focus**.

As you can see this is very vage and there are situations, where the `CommandManager` simply cannot know:

> In situations where the `CommandManager` does not sufficiently determine a change in conditions that cause a command to not be able to execute, `InvalidateRequerySuggested` can be called to force the `CommandManager` to raise the `RequerySuggested` event.

In summary, yes, the `RequerySuggested` event is raised when user input changes and on other input related events e.g. in a `TextBox` or bound properties change, but not in all situations. From a different perspective, the `CommandManager` determines when it needs to raise the event only on *general triggers*, so often it will invalidate *all* can execute states, although most or even no command might even be affected. It is not targeted to the specific case, like a distinct property that you want to observe for changes, but like a watering pot. This can of course make a difference in performance, although negligible in the majority of applications.

---

> ***I put breakpoint on `CanExecute` methods of my commands and saw that they work forever in debug***

Yes and by now you know exactly why. In debug mode when a breakpoint is hit, the debugger or IDE is brought into foreground meaning the keyboard focus changes. When you switch back to your application being debugged, the keyboard focus changes again...and again...and again. Since the `CommandManager` raises the `RequerySuggested` event on keyboard focus, you will constantly trigger `CanExecute` and hit the breakpoint. The same may happen on window activation as well.

---

### A Different Command Approach

There is another very common approach for notifying can execute changed. In your example, you rely on the `CommandManager` to do its best for all commands. However, you could also take responsibility yourself and explicitly invalidate can execute through another public method.

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
   private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
   private readonly Action<T> _execute;

   public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, null)
   {
      _execute = execute;
   }

   public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
   {
      _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
      _canExecute = canExecute;
   }

   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
   {
      return _canExecute == null || _canExecute((T)parameter);
   }

   public void Execute(object parameter)
   {
      _execute((T)parameter);
   }

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

   public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
   {
      CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}
```

Here you assume that you know exactly when to update your own command. Instead of asking "Dear command manager, please tell me when to update" you say "Update these specific commands now". For this you have to call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` for each *affected* command in your properties.

```
public string UserInput
{
   get { return _userInput; }
   set
   {
      if (UserInput != value)
      {
         _userInput = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("UserInput");
         AddTextCmnd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
         ClearTextCmnd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
         ShowResultCmnd.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
      }
   }
}
```

This mechanism has a few advantages over the `RequerySuggested` event.

- You decide exactly when commands are updated.
- Only commands that are really affected are updated.
- It is much easier to comprehend the dependencies in your view model.
- Potential performance benefit from reducing unnecessary updates.
- No reliance on an external component and hidden magic or vage assumptions.

### A Hint On DRY and Reusability

As of now, all of your commands contain duplicated logic, violating the [*Don't repeat yourself* principle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself), in short DRY. This makes maintenance much harder. Instead you should at least extract a common, reusable command type as shown above to improve your code. You do not even have to implement one yourself, there are plenty of frameworks, libraries and NuGet packages available already, e.g. [Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm/), see its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) here.

Here is an example how it would look like for your clear text command:

```
public ViewModel()
{
   ClearTextCmnd = new RelayCommand(ExecuteClearText, CanExecuteClearText);
   // ...other commands.
}

public ICommand ClearTextCmnd { get; set; }

public bool CanExecuteClearText()
{
   return UserInput != "0";
}

public void ExecuteClearText()
{
   UserInput = "0";
}
```

For simplicity I used a `RelayCommand` implementation without an extra parameter, as you do not use it currently. It is the same as the command above, only without the parameter for each method.

---

As asked in the comments, this would be the `RelayCommand` implementation without parameter.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
   private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
   private readonly Action _execute;

   public RelayCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, null)
   {
      _execute = execute;
   }

   public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
   {
      _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
      _canExecute = canExecute;
   }

   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
   {
      return _canExecute == null || _canExecute();
   }

   public void Execute(object parameter)
   {
      _execute();
   }

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

   public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
   {
      CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}
```

Comment: @NoName I have added an implementation for a `RelayCommand` without parameter. Essentially, you have to replace the `Predicate<T>` delegate (which expects a parameter) with a `Func<bool>`, which is a delegate for a method without parameters that returns `bool`.

Comment: I am very sorry. `(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, null)` what does this do ? I can't understand syntax.

Comment: @NoName From [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors): _"A constructor can invoke another constructor in the same object by using the `this` keyword."_ It simply calls the second constructor with the `exceute` parameter and `null` for the `canExecute` parameter. If you reuse another constructor, you do not have to duplicate its code in current one.